# Syntax error in LTspice

Tags: ltspice

I researched online and came across a code given [here](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/ltspice-voltage-controlled-pwm.26887/) for PWM source in LTSPICE.
When I save this .asc and try to open the same, I get the following error:

> Aborting:
>
> Unknown schematic syntax:
>
> SHEET 1 880 680

[image: LTSpice IV Error Message]

How do I solve such an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i was not able to get an answer, i looked for alternatives for a PWM source and found one. IT DOES NOT ANSWER THIS QUESTION but does help if someone wants to include a PWM source in there schematic. 
[image: Here you will find a snapshot of the PWM source with the required details]

Thank you!